# linq to XML as a gridview datasource

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to get all the email nodes for the customers in the sample xml and binding it to a grid.  I can't seemt to get past the linq query!

Sample XML:

```
<group>
<customer>
<email>testing@testing.com></email>
</customer>
<customer>
<email>testing2@testing.com</email>
</customer>
</group>

var query = from result in xml.Elements("customer")
select new
{
email = xml.Element("email").Value
};

gridview1.DataSource = query;
gridview1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Can you please write your XML structure properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements() will only get you direct children, therefore, if your xml variable is an XDocument, its only direct children (according to the little sample) are group elements.

Try:

```
var query = from result in xml.Descendants("customer")
select new { email = result.Element("email").Value };
```